# VBA autofilling multidimensional arrays

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

As a beginner, I would like to ask if it is possible in VBA to autofill formulas in a multidimensional array.

Ι thought and wrote this code and it works with values but not with formulas.

I think that what I am trying to do is very ambitious for my skills

```
 Sub eucldiist()
     Dim e(10,10) As Double, i As Integer, j As Integer
     For i = 1 To 10
         For j = 1 To 10
             e(i, j).FormulaArray = "=sqrt((offset('Data1'!$Q$14,$BD$5(offset(i)) -
 offset('Data1'!$Q$14,$BD$5(offset(j))^2+ ((offset('Data1'!$U$14, 
 $BD$5(offset(i))-OFFSET('Data1'!$U$14,$BD$5(offset(j)))^2)"
         Next j
     Next i

     Sheets("Calculations").Select: Range("A20").Select

     For i = 1 To 10
         For j = 1 To 10
             ActiveCell.Value = e(i, j)
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
         Next j
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, -10).Select
     Next i
 End Sub
```

Is it possible what I am trying to do?

Comment: you fill up one array and then you transfer values into the second array. ... why don't you just fill the second array in the first place and don't use the first array?

Comment: your formula is invalid in VBA ... please post the working formula taken from the `top left cell of the formula array` on the worksheet

Comment: @jsotola the excel formula is: 
(1,1) =SQRT((OFFSET(DATA1!Q14;BD5;0)-OFFSET(DATA1!Q14;BD7;0))^2+((OFFSET(DATA1!U14;BD5;0)-OFFSET(DATA1!U14;BD7;0))^2))

(1,2)= SQRT((OFFSET(DATA1!Q14;BD6;0)-OFFSET(DATA1!Q14;BD7;0))^2+((OFFSET(DATA1!U14;BD6;0)-OFFSET(DATA1!U14;BD7;0))^2))

(1,2) =SQRT((OFFSET(DATA1!Q14;BD5;0)-OFFSET(DATA1!Q14;BD8;0))^2+((OFFSET(DATA1!U14;BD5;0)-OFFSET(DATA1!U14;BD8;0))^2))

Comment: what I am trying to do is to clear the contents of the cells and then refill them. I am running optimization problems using genetic algorithms via palisade evolver software and i would like to reduce calculations. I would like to ask you too if it is possible in VBA to deactivate calculations of certain cells. (Formulas in those cells staying there, for example with zero value, but without taking part in recalculations). I will be appreciated with your help

Comment: the excel formula I wrote is for the tree top left elements of the matrix (1,1), (1,2), (2,1)

Comment: i forgot to say, an array is not an object. it does not have the `.FormulaArray` property ... you probably got an error, but you failed to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

check this out.  put some formulas in a20:j29 before hand

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim aaa As Variant
    aaa = Range("a20").Resize(10, 10).Formula

    Stop  ' now examine aaa in "locals" window 

    ' maybe all you want is this

    range("a20").Resize(10,10).FormulaArray = "=SQRT((OFFSET(DATA1!Q14,BD5,0)-OFFSET(DATA1!Q14,BD7,0))^2+((OFFSET(DATA1!U14,BD5,0)-OFFSET(DATA1!U14,BD7,0))^2))"


End Sub
```

Comment: i just realized that the formula is actually invalid

Comment: Thanks for your comments and your help. I fill the array with without offset commands (data are in two columns). I am doing that with offsets to earn some time because i need to repeat it in other 9 arrays  trying to solve a qap problem. (I think something is wrong with synttax)

Comment: you have unicode characters in your formulas, so i could not get it going.  i corrected the posted answer   .... try `range("a20").Resize(10,10).FormulaArray = "=SQRT((OFFSET(DATA1!Q14,BD5,0)-OFFSET(DATA1!Q14,BD7,0))^2+((OFFSET(DATA1!U14,BD5,0)-OFFSET(DATA1!U14,BD7,0))^2))"`

Answer (score 0):

i think that this is what you want

NOTE: formula uses absolute addressing, so a column or row insert will break it

delete `$` from formula to make it use relative addressing

```
Sub eucldiist()

    Dim base As Range
    Set base = Sheets("Calculations").Range("A20")
'   Set base = ActiveSheet.Range("A20")

    Dim formula As String

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 0 To 9            ' rows
        For j = 0 To 9        ' columns
            formula = "=sqrt(" _
                    & "   (offset('Data1'!$Q$14,$BD$" & 5 + i & ",0) - offset('Data1'!$Q$14,$BD$" & 7 + j & ",0))^2" _
                    & " + (offset('Data1'!$U$14,$BD$" & 5 + i & ",0) - offset('Data1'!$U$14,$BD$" & 7 + j & ",0))^2" _
                    & ")"
    '       Debug.Print formula
            base.Offset(i, j) = formula
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: that was what I want!! thank you so much. Your help was very important!!

Comment: I will continue in the same way to fill all the other matrices of my project! thank you again @jsotola